Laravel recursive Category list with checkbox
How can I query the categories so that the parent and its related children are displayed in a single row?
Example datatbase:
id   parent_id  name
1        0      Category
2        1      subCat 1
3        2      subsubCat 1
4        0      Category 2
5        3      subCat 2

Code:
public static function getCategories($categories, &$result, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $cats = $categories->filter(function ($item) use ($parent_id) {
        return $item->parent_id == $parent_id;
    });

    foreach ($cats as $cat)
    {
        $result[$cat->id] = $cat->name;
        self::getCategories($categories, $result, $cat->id);
    }

    return $result;
}

public static function index()
{
    $categories = PropertyCategory::select('id', 'parent_id', 'name')->get();
    $result = [];
    return self::getCategories($categories, $result);
}

Example list (This is the layout I would like to achieve):
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="scales" value="3" />
  <label for="scales">Category -> subCat 1 -> subsubCat 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="scales" value="5" />
  <label for="scales">Category 2 -> subCat 2</label>
</div>


do you have a max nesting level, like 2 or 3? or can it be anything?

It would be great if the depth were unlimited.

unlimited depth is not easy, but this is a good discussion of various options with pros and cons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database
